# How to stop lsp-mode converting C/C++ includes into buttons?

Tags: lsp-mode

When `lsp-mode` is enabled all headers become clickable (draw as buttons), underlining them making them slightly harder to read.

I don't need this since I can have a key bound to go to the header.

Is there a way not to highlight headers in C/C++ with lsp-mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `lsp-enable-links` to nil. This will disable `lsp-mode`'s link support.